# Нужно ли обособлять приложение?

Tags: обособление

Приложения в приведенных примерах не обособляются. Правильно ли это? Где здесь приложение и определяемое слово?

(1) Мой друг художник и поэт в дождливый вечер на стекле Мою любовь нарисовал, открыв мне чудо на земле.

Также:

(2) Мой друг художник  (название сайта).

(3) Мой друг художник  нарисовал мой  портрет по памяти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В 1-м предложении приложения в постпозиции, а во 2-м и 3-м возможны варианты, поэтому сам автор решает, где приложение.

(1) Мой друг, художник и поэт, в дождливый вечер на стекле Мою любовь нарисовал, открыв мне чудо на земле. / Мой друг - художник и поэт - в дождливый вечер на стекле Мою любовь нарисовал, открыв мне чудо на земле.

Главное слово - "друг", а "художник" и "поэт" - однородные одиночные приложения после определяемого слова, уже имеющего определение.

(2.1) Мой друг художник.

Главное слово - "художник", а "мой друг" - распространенное приложение в препозиции.

(2.2) Мой друг, художник.

Главное слово - "друг", а "художник" - одиночное приложение после определяемого слова, уже имеющего определение.

(3.1) Мой друг художник нарисовал мой портрет по памяти.

Главное слово - "художник", а "мой друг" - распространенное приложение в препозиции.

(3. 2) Мой друг, художник, нарисовал мой портрет по памяти.

Главное слово - "друг", а "художник" - одиночное приложение после определяемого слова, уже имеющего определение.

**ОТВЕТ НА КОММЕНТАРИЙ**

Вообще-то в "Неведомый странник, голубь прячется от грозы на крыше" можно проследить обстоятельственное значение: голубь - странник, своего дома нет, к тому же неведомый, то есть не имеющий здесь знакомых, поэтому и прячется на крыше, а не в доме.

Что касается правила, ПАС его упростил. Теперь акцентируется не определяемое слово (нарицательное или собственное), а препозиция, к тому же введена аналогия с общими правилами обособления определений. В препозиции распространенное приложение без обстоятельственного значения, как и определение, запятыми не выделяется.

Ведь странно: почему причастный оборот перед определяемым существительным не выделяется запятыми, а распространенное приложение должно выделяться? Интонация-то одинаковая.

*Усыпанные листьями поляны были полны солнца.*

*Символ молодости и красоты лотос  – живой свидетель многих геологических эпох.*

*Поручик царской армии Василий Данилович Дибич пробирался из немецкого плена на родину.*

Но примеров необособления ПАС не приводит (в нем вообще многих примеров не хватает).

Comment: 1) Почему здесь невозможно раздельное написание, которое применяется по факту? (Сравнить: В университете студенты филологи и юристы  получают фундаментальное образование. В этой лаборатории работают студенты и аспиранты физики). 2) Распространенное приложение в препозиции, отнесенное к нар.сущ., можно не обособлять? Кажется, в правилах указывается только вариант с собств. сущ.

Comment: ПАС: § 62. Распространенные приложения, стоящие перед определяемым словом, выделяются запятыми (условия обособления совпадают с условиями обособления при согласованных определениях, см. § 46 — 48):
1) если имеют, кроме определительного значения, еще и обстоятельственный оттенок;
2) если относятся к личным местоимениям.
То есть в других случаях не обособляются.  
И из правил об определениях: Определительный оборот, стоящий перед определяемым существительным, не отделяется запятой от определяемого слова, если не осложнен обстоятельственным оттенком значения.

Comment: И ответ Грамоты: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EC%EE%E9+%E4%F0%F3%E3+%E0%EB%EA%EE%E3%EE%EB%FC

Comment: Меня интересует правило, которое приводит Серж: "Если распространенное приложение относится к НАРИЦАТЕЛЬНОМУ существительному, то оно обособляется в любом случае". Из этого следовало обособление "Неведомый странник, голубь прячется от грозы на крыше". Здесь нет обстоятельственного значения, так почему обособляется приложение?

Comment: Студенты филологи и юристы - это о том, почему исчезает дефис, изначально должно было быть "студенты-филологи". А "мой друг художник" изначально без дефиса: или раздельно, если распространенное приложение в препозиции, или с запятой, если одиночное приложение стоит после определяемого существительного, которое имеет при себе пояснительные слова.

Comment: Правило, которое приводит Серж, не соответствует действительности (ПАСу и Грамоте.ру не соответствует). Хотя из формулировки Розенталя такой вывод сделать можно: "Обособляется распространенное приложение, выраженное именем существительным нарицательным с зависимыми словами и относящееся к нарицательному существительному (обычно такое приложение стоит после определяемого слова, реже – впереди него)". Видимо, эта норма меняется. По ПАСу было бы "неведомый странник голубь".

Comment: "Неведомый странник, голубь прячется от грозы на крыше". Это цитата, и без обособления читается намного хуже. А Вы можете привести подобные примеры без обособления из реальных  художественных текстов?

Comment: Спасибо, вы помогли мне прояснить обстановку. Думаю, дело не в меняющихся правилах (они просто фиксируют положение дел), а в том, то стал ОСОЗНАВАТЬСЯ общий принцип решения для определений и приложений. Распространенные необособленные приложения, отнесенные с НАР. сущ., встречаются не часто, и у них всегда какая-то особенная структура, ПОМОГАЮЩАЯ ОПРЕДЕЛИТЬ синтаксическую роль приложения. В примере с лотосом это тире, на котором строится интонация. Для сравнения: Символ молодости и красоты, лотос является живым свидетелем..." Тем не менее, они имеют право на существование.

Comment: @tat,только заметил.Вы утверждаете, что в первом примере (2.1) "главное слово - "художник", а "мой друг" - распространенное приложение в препозиции.", а во втором (2.2) "главное слово - "друг", а "художник" - одиночное приложение после определяемого слова, уже имеющего определение".Но ведь по правилам ,которые я привел, именно в первом примере (2.1), а не во втором(2.2),нужна запятая. Т.к. согласно правилам "Если приложение относится к нарицательному существительному,то оно обособляется в любом случае, вне зависимости от места в предложении.".Я бы поменял запятые.(2.1)с запятой, (2.2)- без.

Answer (score 1):

Все варианты имеют право на жизнь, всё возможно объяснить.

(1) Мой друг художник и поэт в дождливый вечер на стекле

Мою любовь нарисовал, открыв мне чудо на земле.

Кто?-друг-подлежащее.Он есть кто?-художник и поэт - два однородных одиночных приложения. Если бы было одно приложение, мы бы поставили дефис: друг-художник, друг-поэт. В данном случае при определяемом сущ.два нераспространённых приложения - раздельно:Студенты филологи и журналисты...

Если бы автор сделал паузу и выделил приложение, придав ему пояснительный смысл, нужно было бы его обособить запятыми."Мой друг, художник и поэт, в дождливый вечер на стекле..."

(2) Мой друг художник (название сайта).Автор оформил как назывное. Согласна с объяснением tat. Можно было оформить и как двусоставное с тире между подлежащим и сказуемым: Мой друг - художник. И дефисное написание объясняется - два нарицательных существительных, сливающихся по смыслу.
(3) Мой друг художник нарисовал мой портрет по памяти.Тоже согласна с tat.Приложение в препозиции.

Многое зависит от смысла, который вкладывает автор. На то и русский язык, который позволяет передать различные оттенки смысла с помощью синтаксиса.

Comment: Пример "студенты филологи и журналисты" не подходит. У нас не "друг художник и поэт", а "МОЙ друг, художник и поэт" - определяемое существительное имеет при себе пояснительное слово, по правилу нужно обособление.

Comment: Это же поэзия, автор даёт своё вИдение, не всегда советуясь с ПАС. Нам нужно только понять его. А правила меняются.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуй, дам профанский ответ.

1. Мой друг, художник и поэт, в дождливый вечер на стекле... (дальше не буду писать). На мой взгляд, в данном случае постановка дефиса невозможна: присутствует слово "поэт". Главным словом является слово **друг**, а зависимыми - **художник и поэт**.
2. Мой друг-художник. Или же "Мой друг - художник". Отсутствует глагол-связка - ставим тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. "Мой друг-художник написал картину, которая впоследствии прославилась". В этом предложении есть обособление приложения, присоединяемое дефисом. Например, в предложении "Мой друг-африканец рассказал мне смешную историю, которую я слушал с упоением".
3. Мой друг-художник нарисовал мой портрет по памяти. В данном случае обособлённое приложение присоединяется дефисом, как и в примере номер два.

А вообще, картины, насколько мне известно, не рисуются, а пишутся.

Comment: Различные варианты с дефисом и обособлением, действительно, встречаются, например: "Мой приятель-художник прожил на земле мало лет". В предложении (1) иногда используется обособление. Но меня интересует правильность именно РАЗДЕЛЬНОГО  написания.

Comment: В первом предложении дефис вообще не имеет место быть. 

Если бы в предложении отсутствовало слово «поэт», то следовало поставить дефис, да. Но именно это слово не позволяет ставить дефис. Посему, по мне, следует поставить запятую.

Comment: Tagirix, все предложения были написаны раздельно (без дефиса и обособления). Можно ли оставить такое написание, или это неправильно?

Comment: Вы на мой ответ взгляните, и тогда всё станет ясно (если я, конечно же, правильно написал). У меня в ответе всё написано.

Answer (score 0):

Обособление приложений

1. Приложение как вид определения

Приложение  это определение, которое выражено существительным. Приложение по-новому характеризует предмет, дает ему другое название или указывает на степень родства, национальность, звание, профессию и т. д. Приложение всегда употребляется в том же падеже, что и существительное, к которому оно относится.

Хозяин (и. п.), суровый мужик (и. п.), не рад был ни гостям, ни наживе (Н. Лесков).

Эта повесть принадлежит известному писателю-фантасту (д. п.).

Обратите внимание: если приложение и определяемое им слово выражены нарицательными существительными, то между ними ставится дефис. Например:

Бабочки-капустницы порхали над клумбами.

Если же приложение или определяемое слово выражено именем собственным, дефис ставится только в том случае, когда имя собственное стоит перед именем нарицательным. Сравните два приложения в следующей фразе:

Начиналась Москва с небольшого городища в том месте, где речонка Яуза впадает в Москву-реку (А. Н.Толстой).

Словосочетание речонка Яуза написано без дефиса, так как здесь имя собственное стоит после имени нарицательного, а словосочетание Москву-реку написано через дефис, потому что в нем имя собственное находится перед именем нарицательным.

1. Обособление приложений

Прошлая тема была посвящена постановке знаков препинания в предложениях с определениями. Вы узнали, что определение, относящееся к имени существительному, обособляется только в том случае, если стоит после него, а определение, относящееся к личному местоимению, обособляется всегда, вне зависимости от места в предложении. Сравните пары предложений:

1)  Из комнаты раздавался голос, знакомый с детства и Из комнаты раздавался знакомый с детства голос;

2)  Они, промокшие под дождем, решили отправиться в гостиницу и Промокшие под дождем, они решили отправиться в гостиницу.

Как видите, правило обособления определений состоит из двух основных частей. Теперь обратимся к правилу обособления приложений, которое немного сложнее: в нем будет три пункта, которые нужно запомнить. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что во всех пунктах речь идет о распространенных приложениях (то есть о приложениях, состоящих из нескольких слов).

1)  Если приложение относится к нарицательному существительному, то оно обособляется в любом случае, вне зависимости от места в предложении. Например:

Мой отец, капитан пограничных войск, служил на Дальнем Востоке и Капитан пограничных войск, мой отец служил на Дальнем Востоке.

2)  Если приложение относится к собственному существительному, оно обособляется только в том случае, когда стоит после него. Например:

Иванов, капитан пограничных войск, служил на Дальнем Востоке и Капитан пограничных войск Иванов служил на Дальнем Востоке.

3)   Если приложение относится к личному местоимению, то оно обособляется в любом случае, вне зависимости от места в предложении. Например:

Он, капитан пограничных войск, служил на Дальнем Востоке и Капитан пограничных войск, он служил на Дальнем Востоке.

У этого правила есть несколько примечаний:

1. Иногда приложение, которому придается большое значение в высказывании и которое стоит в конце предложения, может обособляться при помощи тире, а не запятой, например: Подходил к концу август – последний месяц лета.
2. Иногда приложение может начинаться с союза КАК. В таких случаях нужно попробовать заменить этот союз на сочетание В КАЧЕСТВЕ. Если такая замена возможна, то запятые ставить не нужно. Например: Газ как топливо сейчас применяется очень широко. Более подробно правила постановки запятых перед союзом КАК будут рассматриваться в отдельной части нашего курса.

Comment: Серж, у меня как раз определяемым является  нариц. существительное. Вы не разрешаете использовать раздельное написание?

Comment: София, действительно, раздельное написание не подходит. Хотя, думаю, ответы Людмилы и tat были достаточно ясны.

Comment: Серж, вы приводите упрощенные, школьные формулировки правил. На самом деле правил больше и некоторые из них уже откорректированы. Перечитайте мой ответ. 2.1 - в препозиции распространенное приложение, как и согласованное определение, без обстоятельственного значения не обособляется. 2.2 - приложение относится не к слову "друг", а к "мой друг", при определяемом слове есть определение, поэтому по правилу нужна запятая.

Comment: Вы правы. Это согласно ПАСУ. А согласно Грамоте,в) 2.1)запятая нужна.
Вы считаете, что правила Грамоты устарели? Хотя, правила употребления между в приложениях тоже расходятся. Я имею в виду Розенталя и ПАС. Вообще в правилах большой разнобой. Уже не знаешь каким правилам следовать.

Comment: Как раз согласно Грамоте в 2.1 запятой может и не быть - смотря что считать приложением.  http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EC%EE%E9+%E4%F0%F3%E3+%E0%EB%EA%EE%E3%EE%EB%FC

Comment: (2.1) Мой друг(,) художник. Запятая нужна ( прим.мое).

Главное слово - "художник", а "мой друг" - распространенное приложение в препозиции. Художник - нарицательное сущ. По Грамоте: Если приложение ( распространенное -прим.мое) относится к нарицательному существительному, то оно обособляется в любом случае, вне зависимости от места в предложении. Я говорю об этом пункте, - вы тоже? Главное слово - "друг", а "художник" - одиночное приложение после определяемого слова, уже имеющего определение. Здесь запятая не нужна.( прим.мое)(2.2) Мой друг, художник. Вы поставили.

Comment: Выражения "мой друг художник" и "мой друг (художник и поэт)" можно считать одинаковыми, приравняв  сочетание  "художник и поэт" к одному слову. после этого автор может обращаться с ними достаточно свободно: (1) "Мой друг художник и поэт" или (2) "Мой друг, художник и поэт". В первом случае необособленное приложение "мой друг" определяет конструкцию "художник и поэт", несущую основное содержание. Во втором случае определяемое (главное) слово - это "Мой друг", а конструкция "художник и поэт" является обособленным приложением. Из этого следует, что первый вариант ближе к авторской мысли.

Comment: Серж, к 2.2: если при определяемом слове уже есть определение (МОЙ друг), то приложение после него обособляется: мой друг, художник (запятая нужна). Это правило Розенталя, не ПАС.

Comment: Я не говорил, что это Пас. Мы, видимо, не понимаем друг друга. Мой друг(,) художник - распространенное приложение. Относится к нарицательному существительному " художник". Вы поставите здесь запятую? ( Согласно Грамоте).

Comment: София, я с Вами полностью  согласен. Но! Если убрать слово " поет" , останется только "художник".
 Я Предложил такой вариант: Мой друг , художник. Мой друг - распространенное приложение., относится к нарицательному сущ-у " художник", поэтому запятая нужна. 
Мой друг художник  - (2.2) Мой друг, художник. ( Согласно Грамоте).

Главное слово - "друг", а "художник" - одиночное приложение после определяемого слова, уже имеющего определение. Запятая также ставится ( По Розенталю).

Но бы не поставил запятую, если предложение оформлено как назывное. Или тире. Или вообще ничего.